# How to force Gurobi to use presolve phase?

Tags: algorithm, solver, gurobi

I am using the Benders decomposition and solve a linear subproblem at each iteration. To save time, I generate the subproblem out of the benders while loop. At each iteration, I solve the master problem and update one of the subproblem constraints and then optimize the subproblem. Since my subproblem is a large problem, presolve during the model. optimize() may help the algorithm. In this respect, I set model.setParam("presolve",value) with value=-1,1,2 (currently none of these options help me with my problem). In the first iteration, in the presolve phase, rows and columns are removed and the model is solved in a reasonable time. However, in the second iteration, the log does not show any presolve phase and due to the problem structure, it can not solve the lp problem. My question is this: How can I force Gurobi to run the presolve phase while optimizing the problem during each iteration? I do not want to use  p.model.presolve()  and p.optimize() because with this, solver miss the dual information of the removed constraints in problem p and I cannot map the solution of p to the solution of the original problem. In the following, you can find the log of the small instance (I have the same problem in the large instances). As you can see in the second iteration, I don't have the presolve phase.
I'm using Gurobi 9.0.1 with python 3.7.

log of the first iteration:

```
Parameter LogToconsole unchanged
Value: 1 Min: 0 Max: 1 Default: 1
Changed value of parameter presolve to 0
Prev: -1 Min: -1 Max: 2 Default: -1
Changed value of parameter presolve to 2
Prev: 0 Min: -1 Max: 2 Default: -1
timesp0 0.015599727630615234
timesp1 0.0
Gurobi Optimizer version 9.0.1 build v9.0.1rc0 (win64)
Optimize a model with 169068 rows, 994898 columns and 413255 nonzeros
Model fingerprint: 0xb25295a2
Coefficient statistics:
Matrix range [1e+00, 1e+00]
Objective range [7e+00, 5e+01]
Bounds range [0e+00, 0e+00]
RHS range [2e+00, 2e+02]

Concurrent LP optimizer: dual simplex and barrier
Showing barrier log only...

Presolve removed 168720 rows and 993466 columns
Presolve time: 0.48s
Presolved: 348 rows, 1432 columns, 3948 nonzeros

Ordering time: 0.00s

Barrier statistics:
AA' NZ : 2.600e+03
Factor NZ : 7.811e+03 (roughly 1 MByte of memory)
Factor Ops : 1.887e+05 (less than 1 second per iteration)
Threads : 1

Objective Residual
Iter Primal Dual Primal Dual Compl Time
0 1.20101504e+06 -7.22191384e+04 1.30e+04 1.81e-01 7.37e+01 0s
1 6.69083915e+05 -2.77917974e+05 3.86e+03 8.88e-16 1.91e+01 0s
2 1.76532366e+05 -1.19739093e+05 4.58e+02 1.36e-13 2.80e+00 0s
3 1.16881480e+05 2.17202950e+04 1.17e+02 3.11e-14 8.29e-01 0s
4 9.96399143e+04 6.74397912e+04 1.72e+01 6.55e-15 1.97e-01 0s
5 9.45489477e+04 8.41843844e+04 1.97e+00 1.61e-15 5.14e-02 0s
6 9.31070029e+04 9.04034661e+04 4.21e-01 5.00e-16 1.30e-02 1s
7 9.24454455e+04 9.22495713e+04 2.43e-03 3.54e-16 9.34e-04 1s
8 9.24011675e+04 9.24005419e+04 9.00e-06 2.98e-16 2.98e-06 1s
9 9.24007899e+04 9.24007893e+04 1.11e-12 4.07e-16 2.98e-09 1s

Barrier solved model in 9 iterations and 0.51 seconds
Optimal objective 9.24007899e+04

Crossover log...

60 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00 1s
0 DPushes remaining with DInf 0.0000000e+00 1s

789 PPushes remaining with PInf 0.0000000e+00 1s
0 PPushes remaining with PInf 0.0000000e+00 1s

Push phase complete: Pinf 0.0000000e+00, Dinf 0.0000000e+00 1s

Iteration Objective Primal Inf. Dual Inf. Time
852 9.2400790e+04 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1s

Solved with barrier
Solved in 852 iterations and 0.75 seconds
Optimal objective 9.240078950e+04
```

log of the second iteration:

```
Parameter LogToconsole unchanged
Value: 1 Min: 0 Max: 1 Default: 1
Changed value of parameter presolve to 0
Prev: 2 Min: -1 Max: 2 Default: -1
Changed value of parameter presolve to 2
Prev: 0 Min: -1 Max: 2 Default: -1
timesp0 0.03119945526123047
timesp1 0.0
Gurobi Optimizer version 9.0.1 build v9.0.1rc0 (win64)
Optimize a model with 169068 rows, 994898 columns and 413255 nonzeros
Coefficient statistics:
Matrix range [1e+00, 1e+00]
Objective range [7e+00, 5e+01]
Bounds range [0e+00, 0e+00]
RHS range [2e+00, 2e+02]
Iteration Objective Primal Inf. Dual Inf. Time
0 -1.6398982e+03 8.440500e+04 0.000000e+00 0s
5061 8.4524006e+04 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 5s
```

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can show the relevant part of the code that you used? And there is no reason to change a parameter twice.

Comment: When I rename the model at each iteration gurobi pre-solve the model during model.optimize().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, the solver is warm-starting from the previous optimization. This will happen if you just change a few parts of the model and don't construct a new model from scratch. Maybe, you can try to call [Model.reset()](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/py_model_reset.html) to start a new optimization from scratch with full presolving.

It's hard to tell what you're doing without seeing the source code, though.